# how to change the style sheet of a page based on the option from the drop-down menu

Tags: php, html, css

i'm creating a page which has an link with the external style sheet, now i created few more style sheets and added an drop-down menu in the page, now how to link these options with the external style sheets so that once the user selects an option from the drop-down menu, the style sheet of that page should totally get changed to the new style sheet...how can i do this?

```
<div style="float:right;padding:26px 0 0 0;color:#fff;"><select>
      <option>please select your choice</option>
<option value="one">green</option>
<option value="two">red</option>
</select>

</div>
```

I have the drop-down as above..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    try this :)

1. give a id to your select box say(giveAId)
2. then in jquery function pass this id and apply a change function('this will notice the   the change made in your select box').
3. get it's value from option box 
4. then pass it to the link href like in this example


 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#giveAId").change(function(){ //2 step
           var stylesheet = $(this).val(); // 3 step
           $('link').attr('href',stylesheet+ '.css'); //4 step done here
          });
    });

 </script>


    <div  style="float:right;padding:26px 0 0 0;color:#fff;">
       <select id="giveAId"> // 1 step
          <option>please select your choice</option>
          <option value="one">green</option>
          <option value="two">red</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: almost the same i was looking for can u please change this into an readable code and where u given the function to call from the select tag??

Comment: @abc123 is it fine ? tell me if i have to elaborate more :)

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$(function1() {
        $("#theme_changer").change(function2(){ 
           var stylesheet = $(this).val();
           $('link').attr('href="style1.css"','"stylesheet"'+ '.css'); 
          });
    });

</script> i tried like this but found no change in my theme???

Comment: $('link').attr('href="style1.css"','"stylesheet"'+ '.css');    with        $('link').attr('href',stylesheet+ '.css');  and edit function1 to function only why are adding 1 and 2 to function...leave them at it is.....

Comment: just copy paste the code and u can change the select box id......and your css name should be what are putting in options value....

Comment: but how to load the different style sheets here??? i want to load style1.css when option value 1 is selected....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11969/discussion-between-abc123-and-sandeep-kumar)

Answer (score 0):

You can give the user a cookie which remembers which style sheet they have chosen from the menu, and load the CSS for the page based on that cookie.  Then just make it so the page refreshes on click, using AJAX if you want.

Comment: yes this gives me an another better idea thanks fr the help...is there any other way like u said using ajax we can change the style sheet...but how to load the style sheet into the page is my doubt in this case...

Comment: else is it possible to call the style sheets by giving the onChange function at the select box??

Answer (score 0):

submit the form and use session/cookies to remember the selection

for example

```
$_SESSION['selected_stylesheet'] = $_POST['stylesheet'];
```

and then u should use the $_SESSION['selected_stylesheet'] when u calling the external css file

```
<link type="text/css" href="<? echo $_SESSION['selected_stylesheet'] ?>.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

i think that will work

Comment: the idea is good but unfortunately i don't have anything in the page to submit and the $_POST method can not be used in my page....

Comment: but u can use javascript to detect the selected option.
im just giving the rough idea on what have i done before in my previous project